# What if i had viruses on windows 8 and install windows 10?

Tags: windows

Does that staff will pass on windows 10, probably there is option for erase all, format hard disk, but sure there is some option for saving files?

Comment: Looking for an answer too.... :(

Comment: If you have a virus, nuke the machine, and do a new installation. Restore your files from a backup. However, the answer is: it depends on what the virus is and does. Since we don't know, we can't answer, hence, I'm voting to close this as too broad.

Comment: Unless you do a clean install, after you do the upgrade, you will end up just having a virus on Windows 10 instead of Windows 8.1.  Somebody else will have to fix the obvious grammatical mistakes with this question, the changes I would make, would actually change the question.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing you do on your current machine can be trusted to give you a "clean" install.

1. Back up your important files to some kind of external media. Do not backup executables of any kind as they are all potentially suspect now.
2. Update your current Windows to Windows 10 and retrieve your product key from it.
3. *On a known virus free computer* download the [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and create a DVD or USB stick for the install
4. Nuke the install by booting from the memory stick or DVD and  performing a "clean" install, using the product key you retrieved in the previous steps.
   Make sure you nuke your existing partitions and install to a clean disk.
5. Restore your files from your backup.

Comment: My q isn't how to save files, but thanks on advice

Comment: If you have viruses on Windows 8 and you do not follow the steps that I stated, then you will almost certainly still have viruses in Windows 10.

Comment: @RadijatoR any option that you follow that saves your files or settings will almost certainly save the virus for you too. A completely clean install is the only guaranteed way to get rid of the virus.

Comment: Depends on the type of virus. Malware that doesn't live in files may survive this. Wasn't it Apple that had some sort of issue where the keyboard firmware could act as a carrier? And then there's hard drive firmware or host protected area malware such as the [Equation Group](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/82356/2138) malware. Granted this might not be what the OP is considering, but neither of these would be wiped by the steps you list.

Comment: Admittedly I wasn't really considering vectors such as BadUSB or device firmwares being hacked, but if you have that level of infestation then there's nothing you can do short of incinerating the machine and buying a machine pre-infected with NSA or Chinese firmware malwares....